# How to resolve Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function?

Tags: javascript

I'm having the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

And I can't figure out what is creating this error, I've tried searching, but haven't found a fitting answer.

input data:
algusLoppPikkus={"first":[58.6666,23.6666,10],"first":[58.6866,23.6866,10],"first":[58.6666,23.6666,15],"first":[58.6666,23.6666,12],"first":[58.6666,23.6666,12],"first":[58.6666,23.6666,13],"first":[58.6666,23.6666,13]}
var kohadID=[10,15,13,12];

```
var Kkordinaadid = {};

function containsObject(ac, arr1, arr2, list) {
    var i;
    if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(list).length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (list[i].ID != ac) {
                var obj = {
                    "ID": ac,
                    "Coord": [arr1, arr2]
                };
                list.push(obj);
            }
        }
    } else {
        var obj = {
            "ID": ac,
            "Coord": [arr1, arr2]
        };
        list.push(obj);
    }
    console.log(list);
}



//var a = containsObject(obj, list);
for (i = 0; i < kohadID.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < algusLoppPikkus.length; j++) {
        if (kohadID[i] == algusLoppPikkus[j].first[2]) {
            containsObject(kohadID[i], algusLoppPikkus[j].first[0], algusLoppPikkus[j].first[1], Kkordinaadid);
            //console.log("koht :" + kohadID[i] + "   "+ "Kordinaat :" +algusLoppPikkus[j].first[0]+" , "+algusLoppPikkus[j].first[1] + " ID : "+ algusLoppPikkus[j].first[2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Chrome's console said the error arises from `list.push(obj);`, but I'm not sure why that happened.

Comment: What's your input data? More importantly, what are you trying to do?

Comment: im trying to add data from 2 arrays , i want to make function that add data only when its not in new array jet

Comment: Tom , list is Kkordinaadid object holder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is rather simple: you invoke `containsObject` as shown below:

```
containsObject(..., ..., ..., Kkordinaadid);
```

Where the last argument passed is `Kkordinaadid`, which however is defined earlier as

```
var Kkordinaadid = {};
```

`Object`s don't have a method called `push`, did you mean to create an array instead?

```
var Kkordinaadid = [];
```

Comment: okey, i understand , but can you give me tip how can i push my object then ?

Comment: If you want to add an element to an object, you will need to give it a key. How you choose to do this is up to you and depends largely on how you plan to use the data later.

Comment: Tnx m8, im really grateful for your help. Im trying on my own now :)